# Injured my wrist in Krav Maga 8 months ago and now it hurts again

Tags: krav-maga

I started Krav Maga lessons last January (2015). In my 4th or 5th session, I injured my wrist. I didn't feel it immediately, but after some hours it started hurting. I went to the doctor; they took x-rays but couldn't see anything broken. They wrapped it up and told me not to use my hand for the next 3 weeks.

After three weeks my wrist was much better, but I still had pain when swimming or doing push-ups (last June).

This September, I decided to give Krav Maga another try. I talked to my instructor about my wrist problem and he said that maybe it's good not to punch hard with my right hand. As a beginner, that's kind of difficult to control.

After the first training session, I actually felt my wrist hurting again. Not so much as previously, but a small constant pain on the upper part of my palm (the extension of the middle finger).

I plan to visit a doctor and get a CT (x-rays don't always show everything). My question is what should I do:

- Should I continue Krav Maga and really try not to use my right hand so much (is this even possible)?
- Should I stop Krav Maga once and for all (also any other martial art)?
- Should I take a break (from the break) and when I feel better then start strengthening my wrist with some exercises?

Comment: Personally I'm inclined to close this question as being too broad, primarily opinion based and also asking for general medical advice (from strangers on the internet....). However I'll let the community tend to that. The absolute first thing you must do before asking any questions about this problem is see a specialist/professional. Until you have solid facts and medical opinion all we can do is speculate and offer general common sense advice.

Comment: Make sure you're going to a doctor that specializes in sports medicine. You need a practitioner whose goal is the same as yours: not to get to a pain-free state, but to get to your previous active level of capability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you definitely need to see a doctor about your injury! Once you have a clearer idea of what is actually wrong, you'll have a better idea of what you can and can't do.

Until that point, though, I would suggest that further training in Krav Maga (or any other martial art!) is likely to make the injury worse. It could also make it harder to recover from the injury properly.

Wishing you a speedy recovery!